# How to distribute apk to limited users. And they cannot re-distribute to others?

Tags: android, google-play-services

How to distribute apk to limited users. And they cannot re-distribute to others?

- One way to do is get device IMEI number and post to server to check valid user or not. But I am trying to limit in android code itself to avoid server communication.
- Also as I will not publish app on google play,I am not able to add Google Play Licence Verification library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard code the list of IMEI or device IDs in the app. On launch check the device ID against your white list and either launch or kill the app depending on the result.

Answer (score 10):

Use **Beta-Testing** section from `Play Store`, after uploading your apk on Play Store. You can create a group of user from Google+ and add them in testing section. Follow this :

**Create an App**

Log into the Developer Console and upload an APK. No need to publish it yet.

[image]

Check out the ‘Beta’ tab now, which should show this handy message:

[image]

**Upload Beta APK**

Click the Beta tab and upload the APK again. Publishing from this tab will not push it to the store, but there is a handy button that allows you to promote apps from Alpha to Beta to Prod, which is neat.

[image]

**Create a Test Group**

Using your developer account (it must be the primary google developer account), create a Google+ Community. Public or private, doesn’t matter. (You could use a Google Group too, but Google+ is a pretty good medium for wrangling a beta team, so I’ll recommend it here.)

[image]

Add your Community to the list of testers by clicking “Manage list of testers” and pasting the Community’s URL.

[image]

**Invite Users to Test**

Click publish in the Beta tab. Click again on “Manage list of testers” and there you will find a URL to share with your Community. When they go to that URL, they’ll get a signup prompt (later, a play store link). Roll outs will take anywhere from a minute to a couple hours to propagate,  as with anything on the store.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to do without using any Google account in device

Comment: You can't. If you dont' have Google Account on device, you can't open play store yet.

Comment: I don't think he wants to distribute this via the Google Play Store. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll out a version to a limited amount of users through the play store.

Just have to create a google Group or a Google+ group and follow the instructions here:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en