# Publish a private app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am developping an application and I want to publish it to Google Play so that only my friends can see it on the store and then install it, but I wish everyone else wouldn't even know my app exists.
When publishing to alpha or internal testing in the Play Console, it says that the app needs to be published before the testing link to appear.

I need your help here: how can I publish it in private mode like I said before?
Thanks for your help, and sorry for my bad english :-/ !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh erm...
Well...

It seems that all I did previously was right. In fact, I just had to wait the publication a couple of hours after the manual publishing.
There is 2-3 hours to wait until the link becomes available.

My app is now only available to beta testers.
Thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 0):

Look here I think there is your solution

[Look here I think there is your solution](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Official Document by Google [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en) you cannot publish app for the private user.

However things you can do is to hard code the list of IMEI numbers or Device ID and check the same on your white list(Application side).Allow access if match is found else kill the app.

The other way is to allow  group of people to access your app, by creating a group using Google+ id, who all can access your app.The further notes, steps and other ways on limited Alpha/Beta User can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857157/how-to-distribute-apk-to-limited-users-and-they-cannot-re-distribute-to-others) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176908/publishing-on-google-play-to-a-limited-number-of-users). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just save the apk file and email it to your friends  to let them install it on their device